# Spoof an IP address to test GEOIP lookups with Sitecore 8

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms, sitecore8

I am new to Sitecore. I'm trying to implement following process class to overwrite **GeoIP** values for testing purpose.

I can't find in which **namespace** the class Tracker is situated. Please note that I am using **Sitecore 8** hosted on localhost. [Sitecore Blog: @sitecorejohn blog](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2011/05/spoof-an-ip-address-to-test-geoip-with-the-sitecore-customer-engagement-platform.aspx)

Can some one please help me to resolve this namespace issue.

Thanks.

```cs
namespace Sitecore.Sharedsource.Analytics.Pipelines.StartTracking
{
    using System.Net;

    using Sitecore.Analytics;
    using Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartTracking;

    public class OverrideIPAddress
    {
        public void Process(StartTrackingArgs args)
        {
            if (Tracker.CurrentVisit == null
              || Tracker.CurrentVisit.GeoIp == null
              || Tracker.CurrentVisit.Ip == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            string ip = new IPAddress(
              Tracker.CurrentVisit.GeoIp.Ip).ToString();

            if (ip != "0.0.0.0" && ip != "127.0.0.1")
            {
                return;
            }

            string html = Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ExecuteWebPage(
              "http://www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp");
            IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(html);
            Tracker.CurrentVisit.GeoIp =
              Tracker.Visitor.DataContext.GetGeoIp(address.GetAddressBytes());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Tracker` class is in the `Sitecore.Analytics` namespace.

Make sure that your project references `Sitecore.Analytics.dll`.

In **Sitecore 8** you should use `Tracker.Current` and  `Tracker.Current.Interaction` instead of `Tracker.CurrentVisit`:

```
Tracker.Current.Interaction.Ip = address.GetAddressBytes();
Tracker.Current.Interaction.UpdateGeoIpData(optionalTimeout);
```

You can consider adding another processor to `CreateVisit` pipeline after `XForwardedFor` processor and call:

```cs
args.Interaction.Ip = address.GetAddressBytes();
```

You won't have to call `UpdateGeoIpData` - it will be called automatically in the `UpdateGeoIpData` processor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I know how this Line of code should be in Sitecore 8? "Tracker.CurrentVisit.GeoIp =
              Tracker.Visitor.DataContext.GetGeoIp(address.GetAddressBytes());"

Comment: This line should be replaced by the 2 lines that are included at the end of my answer - first you set the ip to the address bytes from ip address, and then you execute UpdateGeoIpData with optional timeout (how long do you want to wait for async call to finish).

Comment: Appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @MarekMusielak,
If we are adding your processor just after the existing InitializeTracker processor in the startTracking pipeline defined in Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config file, then do think you you need to update GeoipData as you include in last line of code. Thanks

Comment: You should consider adding another processor to CreateVisit pipeline after `XForwardedFor` processor and set `args.Interaction.Ip = address.GetAddressBytes();` - you won't have to call `UpdateGeoIpData`